# Is there any way to index relationship existence?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Recently i faced with the problem in creating chain of nodes using next query in loop

```
MATCH (p: Node) WHERE NOT (p)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->() 
WITH p LIMIT 1000 
MATCH (q: Node{id: p.id}) WITH p, max(id(q)) as tail
MATCH (t: Node) where id(t) = tail 
WITH p, t
CREATE (p)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(t)
```

The problem appears after creating chain with first ~1 000 000 nodes. Query

```
MATCH (p: Node) WHERE NOT (p)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->()
```

works very slow because it looks through first 1 000 000 and checks if they don't have a relationship, but they all have. At some amount of nodes query ends with "Unknown error". To get around with it I tried next queries.

```
MATCH (p: Node) with p skip 1000000  
Match (p) WHERE NOT (p)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->()
```

or

```
MATCH (p: Node) with p order by id(p) desc  
MATCH (p) WHERE NOT (p)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->()
```

But i wonder if there more elegant way to solve this problem like "indexing relationship existence"?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Do you have an index on :Node(id) ? Make sure with `PROFILE` that the index is used in the second match.

Comment: 2.6 Yes, i have index. The problem is not with second match, i wrote it just for example. The problem that query MATCH (p: Node) WHERE NOT (p)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->()  works extremely poor after y Create relationship for first million nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can index relationship properties using "legacy indexing," which isn't exactly recommended anymore, but this won't index the absence of relationships so it wouldn't do you any good. I'd probably try to find a way to mark nodes in need of relationships through either a label or an index on a property. Start your match from there, it'll be much faster.

Comment: As you say legacy is not indexing recommended anymore , so how to do full text search ? Is there any new way to do full text search

Comment: @abhaygarg12493 I use Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks ,
Actually ,we are in confusion we need data instantaneous data . So we cant wait that about a day for re-index of elastic search . Any other solution ?